# Sort email with descending date

Tags: vba, outlook

I loop through all the emails to find the one with specific subject line.

It always starts from the oldest one and is taking lot of time as mostly the mail required is the latest one.

```
Dim outMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim inputDate As String, subjectFilter As String
Dim saveInFolder As   String
Dim filesys, newfolder, newfolderpath
OutlookOpened = False
On Error Resume Next
Set outApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Set outApp = New Outlook.Application
OutlookOpened = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0

If outApp Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Cannot start Outlook.", vbExclamation
Exit Sub
End If

Set outNs = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set outFolder = outNs.Folders("Personal Folders").Folders("Inbox")  
'Set outFolder = outNs.PickFolder                                   
Set outItems = outFolder.Items

If Not outFolder Is Nothing Then
    outItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", False
    For Each outItems In outFolder.Items
        If outItems.Class = Outlook.OlObjectClass.olMail Then

            Set outMailItem = outItems
            randomdate = Format(outMailItem.SentOn, "dd/mm/yy")
            If outMailItem.Subject = subjectFilter Then

                If randomdate = inputDate1 Then

                    Debug.Print outMailItem.Subject
                    For Each outAttachment In outMailItem.Attachments
                        outAttachment.SaveAsFile saveInFolder & outAttachment.Filename
                    Next
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

I have tried both True and False with sort order.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but why is this tagged Excel and Excel-vba?

Comment: @yu_ominae maybe OP is binding Outlook with Excel?

Comment: either way, it is *mostly* a question pertaining to *Outlook-vba* and the meat of this question pertains to Outlook's object model, not Excel's. I think there is a meta-discussion somewhere about the various VBA application tags...

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to loop through **all** items? Use Items.Find/FindNext to find the match on the value of the Subject property.

```
set outMailItem = outItems.Find("[Subject] = '" & subjectFilter & "'")
```

If you have multiple matches, you can loop through them all using Findf/FindNext

```
set outMailItem = outItems.Find("[Subject] = '" & subjectFilter & "'")
while Not (outMailItem  Is Nothing)
  'do something with outMailItem 
  set outMailItem  = outItems.FindNext
wend
```

Comment: A sample or a link might help I think.

Comment: See above. It is not at all different from your code that sorts the items.

Comment: HI.. Along with subject line there is also another criteria for received date as the same subject line comes every day. The code line mentioned by you is returning "nothing" also i need to navigate through the mail as many mails would have same subject line and from there i will search for the received date. Please suggest a complete code if possible or link where i can get that. Thanks.

Comment: To suggest complete code, you need to provide the complete criteria. Why would you get "nothing" if a message with the given subject exists?

Comment: With the line mentioned i can only find one mail with that subject line. What if i have multiple mails with the same subject line. How do i navigate between them to check for the receiving date ?

Comment: See updated reply above. You can also incorporate extra conditions to the search query, e.g. [Subject] = 'blah' AND ReceivedTime > '2014-08-01'